# What is best solution file upload for python server

Tags: android, python, sockets, raspberry-pi, file-transfer

I programming python server and android client.
program's logic is client send multiple file to server.
I first try C/C++ socket server but receive error. so I change python. because server on raspberry pi.
I have to implement file upload, audio streaming. so I think this logic. 
1. Client send http request to server 
2. When server receives the request, server create tcp socket and listen. 
3. Client receives success response, connect to server and file upload. 
Audio streaming will implement similar way.
Is it ok to implement this way? or is there a better way? 
Please give me a hint how to implement it.

Comment: try retrofit,its a sweet library

Comment: first implement server socket and listen first , after that  send the request to server from client ,then handsake and send response back to client

Comment: @Rajput I have to handle file upload, audio streaming. how do I differentiate between messages and data?

Comment: @Roy Thank you. I will search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore socket as much as you for small deployments. They are little more complicated to handle.

Now asuming you want to upload a image file or some other file to a python you can use [Flask Upload](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/) 

Next move on to audio, if you have to upload audio from client to server, than there is no need to stream or stuff, just pass appropriate [MIME](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) type during upload.

```
ALLOWED_AUDIO_EXTENSIONS = set(['wav', 'ogg', 'mp3', ])

def audio_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_AUDIO_EXTENSIONS

if file and audio_file(file.filename):
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    #perform some application logic with audio files and then save them in file system or call boto3 to save on s3

    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
```

Code is modified from flask examples.